# jquery/js and php communication issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on an simple client/server communication with jquery/JS and PHP. It works fine till a `'.'` is included in the data.

Tried with the following titles:

- `asdf-wq1      --> works`
- `test1         --> works`
- `bigip1.local  --> '.' is replaced with '_'`

I already added the `escape()` function to my code, but the result was the same.

```
function xy(){
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var xy = escape(nodes[i].title) +"=" +escape(nodes[i].translate.x + "/" + nodes[i].translate.y);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_layout.php',
            data: xy,
            dataType: "text",
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                $("#output").html(output);
            },
            error: function (response, status, error) {
                alert("error" + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value) {
     echo "$name $value \n";
}
```

Firebug Output Request:

```
POST http /frontend/save_layout.php

200 OK  186ms   
jquery....min.js (Zeile 4)
HeaderPostAntwortHTML
Parameterapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
bigip1.local 470/390

Quelle
bigip1.local=470/390
```

Firebug Output (Response):

```
bigip1_local 470/390
```

As you can see - it seems to be sent to the server correctly, but on the server as soon as reading our of `$_POST` - the `'.'` is a `'_'` at a sudden.

Hope someone can help me here!

Comment: Try letting jQuery do the encoding: `var xy = {}; xy[nodes[i].title] = nodes[i].translate.x + "/" + nodes[i].translate.y;` That way jQuery will string the post body for you.

Comment: hi! thx for the prompt response - but unfortunately i am still facing the same problem... i can see the correct value "bigip1.local" in the firebug post data, but in php i still get the "bigip1_local" as soon as i access $_POST...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not convert the `data` into a string manually. jQuery does that. Just pass an object instead of a string to the Ajax functions.

And you should never (**never!**) use `escape()`. This function is broken and there is no reason to use it. Use `encodeURIComponent()` in its place, if you must do manual URL encoding for some reason.

```
function xy(nodes) {
    $.each(nodes, function (i, node) {
        $.post("save_layout.php", {
            title: node.title,
            x: node.translate.x,
            y: node.translate.y
        })
        .done(function (output) {
            $("#output").html(output);
        })
        .fail(function (response, status, error) {
            alert("error" + response.responseText);
        });
    });
}
```

Also note a few other changes I've made to your code to make it more idiomatic in the context of jQuery:

- The fact that the `nodes` are passed in as a parameter instead of a global variable. This makes the function more independent.
- The use of `$.each()` to replace your for loop.
- The use of the explicit `$.post()` instead of the more generic `$.ajax()`.
- The fact that all data is passed as a *value*, not as a key. The keys `title`, `x`, `y` will be the same for every request. This makes things easier on the server side (*and* on the client).
- The use of `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks that can be attached to `.post()`, `.get()` and `.ajax()` since their nature is that of a *promise*. You can [read more about `$.Deferred` and promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) or just take this as it is - a very convenient way of working with Ajax callbacks in jQuery.

You might want to think about refactoring the code to something that makes *one* Ajax request with all objects instead of one request for each object. HTTP requests take time, it's best to combine them.

Comment: +1 if this still doesn't solve the issue, then there is a problem on the PHP side.

Comment: it really seems to solve it - i will just test now and confirm and then accept the solution!! thx a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

1. escape is deprecated. better use encodeURIComponent.
2. it your case just use jQuery functionality

   ```
   for (var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {

       var data = {};
       data[nodes[i].title] = nodes[i].translate.x + "/" + nodes[i].translate.y;

       $.ajax({
           url: 'save_layout.php',
           data: data,
           dataType: "text",
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output) {
               $("#output").html(output);
           },
           error: function (response, status, error) {
               alert("error" + response.responseText);
           }
       });

   }
   ```

Comment: hi! thx for the prompt response! i like your approch since it is more straight forward - but unfortunately i am still facing the same problem... 
i added a  window.console.log( [nodes[i].title] ); before the ajax request and it shows the correct value "bigip1.local", but in php i still get the "bigip1_local" as soon as i access $_POST...

Answer (score -1):

In your javascript code you could try using

```
JSON.stringify(values);
```

And then just json_decode() in your php.